# Usiing deepspeech package for automatic speech recognition

Tags: python, api, google-colaboratory, speech-recognition, mozilla-deepspeech

please i need some help.
How can I use deepspeech as an API directly in google colab without using the command prompt : I want to load the pre_trained model,instanciate it and create a function that takes as input and audio file and returns the text.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub repo contains an Google Colab notebook that provides good instructions to get started:

https://github.com/mayukhnair/deepspeech-colab